# How to read a specific value from a JCoTable object

Tags: java, jco

I successfully got the Table entries from a SAP system via `RFC_GET_TABLE_ENTRIES`. It works all fine and lists me all the rows of the table.

My problem right now is that I have no idea how to get a single value out. Usually I would go like codes `[x][y]` but that doesn't work because it is not a normal two-dimensional-array table but a `JCOtable` and I have no idea how that works.

The code is a little longer but this is the call itself.

```
JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("mySAPSystem");
JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("RFC_GET_TABLE_ENTRIES");



if (function==null)
    throw new RuntimeException("Function not found in SAP.");

function.getImportParameterList().setValue( "MAX_ENTRIES", 30);
function.getImportParameterList().setValue( "TABLE_NAME", "ZTEST_TABLE ");
JCoTable codes = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("ENTRIES");
codes.appendRow();
```

and this is the console output

```
System.out.println("RFC_GET_TABLE_ENTRIES");

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    codes.setRow(i);
    System.out.println(codes.getString("WA"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getString`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.sap.cloud/neo-java-web-api/3.11.5.1/com/sap/conn/jco/JCoRecord.html#getString(int)) actually accepts indexes as well. If you want to retrieve values according to x and y you can do the following

```
codes.setRow(y);
String value = codes.getString(x); // It can also be getFloat, getInt, etc. depending on the data type,
                                   // or getValue, which gives you an Object
```

It works similarly to `codes[x][y]` as if it's an array, but this is not commonly used.

In other cases, you may want to iterate through each single value in the row with [`JCoRecordFieldIterator`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.sap.cloud/neo-java-web-api/3.11.5.1/com/sap/conn/jco/JCoRecordFieldIterator.html).

```
JCoRecordFieldIterator itr = codes. getRecordFieldIterator();
while(itr.hasNextField()){
    JCoRecordField field = itr.nextRecordField();
    String value = field.getValue(); // Or getString, getFloat, etc.
    // Whatever you want to do with the value
}
```